# How can I avoid minify Javascript(main.js) on ionic 2 run?

Tags: ionic2

I am using this command to run Ionic 2 project on android

`ionic run -l -c -s --debug android`

after I see such a exception

```
0     214474   error    EXCEPTION: No component factory found for t
1     214477   error    ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
2     214484   error    Error: No component factory found for t at e.Error (native)
at e [as constructor] (http://192.158.0.8:8100/build/main.js:5:5464)
```

The problem is that `ionic run` compiles everything to minified main.js file and it is nearly impossible to understand exceptions or debug on it.

[image]

Is there any way to skip minify step?
Or maybe there is a other solution to debug ionic 2 application?

Comment: Have you tried by changing this line in your `package.json` file: `"ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build --dev"`?

Comment: after your change I got such a error

`
[20:23:53]  lint finished in 2.95 s
[20:23:58]  typescript compiler finished in 8.34 s
[20:23:58]  bundle dev started ...
[20:23:58]  bundle dev failed:  Could not resolve entry (./.tmp/app/main.dev.js)

[20:23:58]  bundle dev failed:  Could not resolve entry (./.tmp/app/main.dev.js)

[20:23:58]  Error: Could not resolve entry (./.tmp/app/main.dev.js) at D:\work\my\ionic\app_type__dream_list_mobile\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:8635:28
Error running ionic app script "build": Error: Could not resolve entry (./.tmp/app/main.dev.js)`

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. What version of Ionic are you using?

Comment: Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1 
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1 
Gulp local: 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0 
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1 
OS: Windows 8 
Node Version: v5.12.0

Comment: If you wish to run AoT but disable minifaction, do the following ionic run android --aot

Comment: no, this `ionic run android -l -c --aot` minify main.js anyway